# Show list user name in form datalist and send the user_id in table

Tags: laravel, crud, datalist

I have form datalist. I want show data user name and send the value user_id by list data user into table. but when I save it, its not send the user_id.

**this my controller**

```
public function create()
{
    $projects = Project::pluck('project_name', 'id');
    $users = User::pluck('name', 'id');
    // dd($users);
    return view ('teams.create', compact('projects', 'users'));
}

/**
 * Store a newly created resource in storage.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $team = Team::create($request->all());
    dd($team);
    return redirect()->route('team.create');
}
```

**this my form datalist**

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="">Name *</label>
    <input list="user_id" name="user_id" class="form-control" placeholder="Input Name">
      <datalist id="user_id" name="user_id">
         @foreach($users as $user)
           <option value="{{$user}}">
         @endforeach
      </datalist>
 </div>
```

**error**
[image: error]

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using `compact` can you generate a new Array to pass to the template?

```
$data = [
  'users' => $users,
  'projects' => $projects
];
return view ('teams.create', $data);
```

Answer (score 0):

The datalist is allow users to enter a custom value which is not in the list. it is not same as like select which have different display value and storing value.

You can use Typeahead instead: http://www.runningcoder.org/jquerytypeahead/demo/ 
which also allow to use id property from user object.

if you type extra value in that you should store that first then get the id of it and then add it to `Team` table.